# Assign the positions of a gameObject from one array variable to another with the same id

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Good morning,

I make a backup system in which

I have 2 array variables, one "enemies" which I filled by doing "enemies = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Enemy")" and the second "enemiesPosition" which I would like to fill like this:

for each gameObject in enemies, find its positions and assign them to the same id in enemiesPosition.

Thanks to this I would like to say that when I save my game, I save all the positions of my enemies and when I come back to the game, the enemies have not moved.

Once the positions have been saved, how do you load them for each of the enemies? (in the loadData() function)

I tested this for save:

```
for(int i = 0; i < enemies.Length; i++)     {       enemiesPositions.[i] = enemies[i].transform.position : " + i);     }
```

and this for load :

```
for (var i = 0; i < savedData.enemies.Length; i++)
        {
            savedData.enemies[i].transform.position = savedData.enemiesPositions[i];
        }
```

### but this returns an error because enemisPositions[] has no objects

The script :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Linq;

public class SaveSystem : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F5))
        {
            SaveData();
        }

        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F9))
        {
            LoadData();
        }
    }

    public void SaveData()
    {
        SavedData savedData = new SavedData
        {
            enemies = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Enemy"),
        };

        string jsonData = JsonUtility.ToJson(savedData);
        string filePath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/SavedData.json";
        Debug.Log(filePath);
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filePath, jsonData);

    //save positions of all enemies
    }

    
    public void LoadData()
    {
        string filePath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/SavedData.json";
        string jsonData = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath);

        SavedData savedData = JsonUtility.FromJson<SavedData>(jsonData);

    //load positions of all enemies
    }
}

public class SavedData
{
    public GameObject[] enemies;
    public Vector3[] enemiesPositions;
}
```

Comment: What error do you get? It looks like a typo to me (remove `.` before indexer). Shouldn't it be `enemies.Positions[i]` ? Or what is `enemiesPositions`? See [mcve].

Comment: I made a typo for enemiesPosition[i] . Otherwise enemiesPositions is an array, I would like it to contain the positions of all enemies in the correct order. Thanks to this, I plan to do when loading my game, find the saved positions of the enemies and assign them. As for the error in unity, I don't have it in front of me right away, I could send it to you this evening only...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it simply by using Linq.

Add this using statement:

```
using System.Linq;
```

And extract the positions this way:

```
enemiesPositions = enemies.Select(enemy => enemy.transform.position).ToArray();
```

---

### Edit following the discussion we had in the comments

Try the following version of the SaveData method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Save the positions of all enemies
/// </summary>
public void SaveData()
{
    GameObject[] gameObjects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Enemy");
    SavedData savedData = new SavedData
    {
        enemies = gameObjects,
        enemiesPositions = gameObjects.Select(e => e.transform.position).ToArray()
    };

    string jsonData = JsonUtility.ToJson(savedData);
    string filePath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/SavedData.json";
    Debug.Log(filePath);
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filePath, jsonData);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but I can't manage to do this for all the game objects (and to reassign them).
I've added the code to my message...

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the problem, what happened when you tried my piece of code?

Comment: When I put your piece of code, it only saved "enemiesPositions[]" in my text file. I tried with a loop but without success... I think I just don't know how to integrate it well and where in my code.

Comment: I'm not sure how you code all goes together but I would assume that my piece of code needs to go inside of the initialization of the SavedData instance savedData you're doing in the SaveData Method, just bellow the enemies field and before closing the curly bracket.

Comment: When I put it in savedData, I get an error message saying "The name 'enemies' does not exist in the current context"... I have to make a loop ? Because this code only saves one position. If so, how do I do it ?

Comment: Yes, it went over my head but referencing the enemies field during the initialisation of the SavedData object will not work. I've updated my answer to include the full SaveData method, tell me if it works now.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! It works perfectly!
One last question, for the load function where I want to reassign all the positions, should I use a loop or make a .ToArray or something like that? I've tried a loop but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: If it is saved correctly the SavedData object should be deserialized entirely from the json.
Could you update your question to include the part that is not working?
And if my answer was helpful could could accept it?

Comment: I've accepted your answer and amended my question. Once the positions have been saved, how do I load them for each enemy? (in the loadData() function).

Comment: I try this :

```
for (var i = 0; i < savedData.enemies.Length; i++)
        {
            savedData.enemies[i].transform.position = 
            savedData.enemiesPositions[i];
        }

```
but it's not working.The enemies return to their initial position.

Comment: Actually, the position of the enemies should be loaded in both arrays. I think your problem has more to do with binding the physical position of an enemy to its value in the array than saving and loading the data.

Comment: So what do I do? I have to admit that I'm still not at my best with arrays :)